# Twilio Cloud Based Functions and Libraries

Tags: twilio

@philnash had a solution `[here][1]` that I tried and had a problem - I'm using Twilio's Cloud Functions and getting no intellisense on client.messages - any idea how to reference the correct library

client.messages.create({

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot, you spelled client wrong, `cleint`.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
    
twilioClient.messages
  .create({
    body: 'Hello World',
    to: '+14075551212',
    from: '+18025551212 ',
  }).then(message =>  {
        console.log('Created call using callback');
        console.log(message.sid);
        callback();
  })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
           callback("error");
    });
};
```

You should update the [Twilio client library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/CHANGES.md) version as well, 3.29.2 is pretty old.

Comment: It happens to all of us, trust me!